# Update Java security policy at runtime?

Tags: java, security, policy

Is there a legal way to add/remove permissions to Java security policy at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

Javadoc says that `Policy.refresh()` for file-based policy would re-read the file. Thus, it is possible to modify system-wide policy at runtime by editing policy file and then calling `Policy.refresh()`

Comment: You'll find that the permissions have already been copied out of the Policy and into the ProtectionDomains of Classes and ClassLoaders.

Comment: This was working fine for me when setting the policy through ``System.setProperty("java.security.policy", policyURL)``, then refreshing ``Policy.policy.refresh()`` and afterwards installing the security manager ``System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());``.

Answer (score 2):

From 1.4 dynamic [`ProtectionDomain`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#ProtectionDomain(java.security.CodeSource,%20java.security.PermissionCollection,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.security.Principal[]))s can delegate to the [`Policy`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Policy.html#getPermissions(java.security.ProtectionDomain)). Dynamically removing permissions from code is unlikely to make any sense. The two argument forms of [`AccessController.doPrivileged`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged(java.security.PrivilegedAction,%20java.security.AccessControlContext)) might also be useful.

Comment: We're developing an OSGi-based framework, which should be long-running and avoid restarts as much as possible. The framework is SAAS, but customer is able to deploy own bundles (plugins) to the system. So, for us it would be nice to modify permissions at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to set custom Policy implementation, using `Policy.setPolicy()` method.