# Java SecurityManager - setting custom policy file

Tags: java, securitymanager

is there a way to create a custom policy file for the Java SecurityManager that is located wherever I want it to be?
If it is, how would I do that, and how would I bind the SecurityManager to that file programmatially, that is not via the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify additional security policy files via the `java.security.policy` JVM argument:

```
java -Djava.security.policy=<path to policy file> MyClass
```

If you wanted the policy file to completely override the system and default user policy files then specify a 'double =' syntax:

```
java -Djava.security.policy==<path to policy file> MyClass
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot execute a command-line command since I don't have access to a command line interface. Is there no way to specify the policy file without such a command, but within the code?

Comment: You do not need to use tue command line. Just configure your startup with the java.security.policy parameter. How exactly is your app launched?

Comment: That's a bit complicated. Right now it is started with Eclipse, but once finished, it will be started differently, and I really don't know if I can set up any startup parameters then. So there is no way to do this within the code?

Comment: Not in my experience. However @BenR claims to have done so in the past, in the first answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011777/update-java-security-policy-at-runtime.